# Docker volume vs mount bind for external hdd

Tags: docker

First time docker ser here, running on Raspberry Pi 3 (Hypriot OS). I have an external hdd attached to my raspberry pi to store all the files. The os is on the sdcard.

I am setting up many images on docker: sonarr, radarr, emby server and bittorrent client.

I have created all containers following the lines on docker hub page, so I attached all of the folders using mount bind (`-v /some/path:/some/path`).

Now the documentation says volume is better because it doesn't rely on filesystem. Also, I am having problems because I want to use hardlink between files on my external hdd, but because I am using mount binds, it seems to not work when calling hardlink from one mount to another on the same hdd. I think adding only one mount bind should solve this but I just want to make the config correct now.

Is volume an option to store all the movies or should I keep using mount bind?

In canse of volume, can I specify the external hdd to store movies? I have docker installed on an sdcard but I need the movies on my external hdd.

I have used `docker create volume --name something -o device=/myhddmount/` but I am not sure if this is ok, because docker volume inspect shows a mountpoint on the sdcard. Also, when I create the volume, should I set `-o type=ext4`? because according to the manual etx4 doesn't has a `device=` option.

Thanks!